# Mapping JSON parameters into python api for vector search in Azure AI search

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I am following this tutorial - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-get-started-vector. Instead of sending calling `post`, I am trying to use `python` api.

For the request

```
POST https://{{search-service-name}}.search.windows.net/indexes/{{index-name}}/docs/search?api-version=2023-11-01
Content-Type: application/json
api-key: {{admin-api-key}}
{
    "count": true,
    "select": "HotelId, HotelName, Description, Category",
    "vectors": [
        {
            "value": [0.01944167, 0.0040178085
                . . . 
                010858015, -0.017496133],
            "k": 7,
            "fields": "DescriptionVector",
            "kind": "vector",
            "exhaustive": true
        }
    ]
}
```

How do the parameters map to `search` api mentioned in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-search-documents/azure.search.documents.searchclient?view=azure-python#azure-search-documents-searchclient-search

So far, I have created

```
search_client.search(query_type='semantic', semantic_configuration_name='my-semantic-config',
    search_text="which restaurant has rating of 4 or over?", 
    select='HotelName,Description,Category', query_caption='extractive',
    vector_queries = [..],
```

Where do I mention other parameters like `k`, `fields`, `kind`, `exhaustive`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be mentioned in the `vector_queries` array of "VectorQuery" objects. The definition is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-search-documents/azure.search.documents.models.vectorquery?view=azure-python

```
search_client.search(query_type='semantic', semantic_configuration_name='my-semantic-config',
    search_text="which restaurant has rating of 4 or over?", 
    select='HotelName,Description,Category', query_caption='extractive',
    vector_queries = [
~~~object here~~~
    ],
```

Comment: I used `VectorisedQuery` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-search-documents/azure.search.documents.models.vectorizedquery?view=azure-python. Thanks for pointing in right direction